# mongoose custom id with populate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

how to use populate to select object by custom object_id so i got

```
 const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    }
    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)
```

and there is a Translation Collection

```
const TranslationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
uuid:{
    type:String,
    required: true,
    index: true
},
locale: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    index: true
},
translation: {
    type: String,
    default:''
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Translation', TranslationSchema);
```

Now book in title and description has an UUID that represents Translation and i want to make .populate('title') and pass title as UUID and locale as string lets say 'en' is it even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best data model for Mongo.  Why not insert your translation schema as a subdocument on book?  What you are describing is a relationship not a document.

Comment: Ye but what is there are many :) I made there a custom query after normal Find that populate the values

Comment: That's the correct way to go for related data in mongo.  Hopefully you don't have too many cases like this.